# How can I make a user enter more letters than 2?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make user enter more than 3 letters for their name I cant seems to figure out how can I do that?

```
while True:
    name = input ("Enter Your Name: ")
    age = int(input("Enter Your age: "))
    if not str(name):
         if len(name) <3 :
            put_text("enter again")
            break
    else:
        put_text("Hi", name, "You are", age, "Years old")
```

Comment: You only want to `break` when things are GOOD.  Move the `break` to the `else` clause.  Also, `name` is guaranteed to be a string.  Your first check is not sensible.

Comment: "break" exits the loop, "continue" goes back to the beginning of the loop.

Comment: What do you expect the `if not str(name)` condition to do?

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need.  Loop until you get success, THEN take your action.

```
while True:
    name = input ("Enter Your Name: ")
    age = int(input("Enter Your age: "))
    if len(name) < 3:
        put_text("enter again")
    else:
        break
put_text("Hi", name, "You are", age, "Years old")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a function and calling it when len of name is less than three

```
def names():
    name = input("Enter Your Name: ")
    age = int(input("Enter Your age: "))
    if len(name) <3 :
        put_text("enter again")
        names() # call names function if len of name is less than 3
    else:
        put_text("Hi", name, "You are", age, "Years old")
        
names()

Enter Your Name:  ab
Enter Your age:  1
enter again
Enter Your Name:  abc
Enter Your age:  1
Hi abc You are 1 Years old
```